# SAXParseException, failed to read schema document

Tags: spring

I got a problem with my applicationContext.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">  

<import resource="classpath:spring/persistence.xml"/>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sgcib.mrp.cva"/> 

<util:properties id="jdbcProps" location="jdbc.properties" />   

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
         <value>classpath:configuration.properties</value>
         <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I get this error :

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

What does it mean ?

Answer (score 11):

That means that the schema file was not available to the application.

You have a few options to solve this:

- Check the internet connection and proxy settings (most probably the SAX parser cannot fetch it due to some connection problems)
- Just download the schema file, add it to your classpath and change the schema location to point to your downloaded file.

Comment: Downloading the schema and referencing it locally worked for me, but this is confusing. Why would the server all of a sudden fail to load that file from the net? :(

Comment: I am was very wonder about mandatory internet connection for my application

Comment: For me, the application is executing from the Eclipse, but the jar execution fails from the command line with the same SAX error. Is there some additional configuration etc, that controls the execution from command line.

Comment: Thank you. For me, it works when downloading the schema and adding it to the project